# Attempting to have separate CSS and HTML files in google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have the following in my HTML:

```
<?!= include('Stylesheet'); ?>
```

include in Code.gs is:

```
function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
      .getContent();
}
```

However, when I load the page, `<?!= include('Stylesheet'); ?>` shows up as plain text and the CSS is not included. I feel like I am making an obvious mistake here, I have read this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices) and I just can't figure it out.

Comment: You may want to share more parts of your code.

Comment: Looks that you already solved the problem. Please instead of editing your question, post the solution as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem, I was using sandbox mode in doGet().

Here is what I did to fix it, I changed

```
function doGet() {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index')
        .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}
```

to

```
function doGet(request)
{
    return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index')
        .evaluate();
}
```